# Cloud based web service for Web Applications

Tags: mysql, sql-server, amazon-web-services, cloud

My web application uses PHP/MySQL on the server side to fetch and store data in a database. The DB size will increase with the user base, and can be huge. The application has been built and run on a conventional server, i.e no "cloud" specific code has been written (I have no experience with cloud systems; Is running services on them any different from running on a normal server?)

My concerns:
1. If I buy space on Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud, can I directly port all my code to the new server, or do I have to use some APIs specific to that? Since it's pay as you go, it's highly suitable for such a requirement.
2. What are the other options for hosting a web service that would require large server space? How might apps like Whatsapp be doing the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The answer to the first question depends on the type of service you're buying. Cloud comes in many forms, from Infrastructure as a Service (which basically offers you hardware as a service on which you can run your software stack) to Software as a Service (e.g. Gmail, which lets you use applications (or APIs) hosted in the cloud ).

The best alternative, in your case I think it is Platform as a Service (e.g Heroku) which defines a set of technologies supported by the provider and how to use them.

Either case, how difficult it is depends on your app and the specification of the service and the level of support offered, so you have to dig a little deeper (starting with guides of how to deploy a similar app would be a good choice).

2) Startups and other medium size companies use cloud providers such as Amazon, Rackspace etc and when they reach a certain size tend to build their own data centers (e.g Zynga). There's a threshold beyond which is better to manage your own infrastructure instead of buying services from others.

Comment: How about the code it self, would there be much code modification when we shift the system to cloud? Thank you for sharing your experience.